# Why isn''t this css trumping this other css?

Tags: html, css, textbox

I have the following css (in this order):

```
textarea, input[type="text"], select {
border: 1px solid #B5B8C8;
}

.ui-state-error, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-error, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-error {
border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
 }
```

and i have a text box that looks like this:

```
  <input type="text" name="Applications" value="" id="Applications" class="fullRowTextBox ac_input ui-state-error" autocomplete="off">
```

and it seems to be using this color:  #B5B8C8 instead of #CD0A0A color.

I thought the CSS below would trump the css above.

Any reasons why this textbox is not getting the #CD0A0A border color?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its a matter of [specificity](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#specificity) as Quentin pointed out.

Think of specificity as four numbers beginning with (0,0,0,0):

1. `!important` rules always take precedence, only another !important
   rule can override a previous one (its an accessibility feature of
   CSS, designed to override the UA stylesheet)
2. The universal selector `(*)` has a specificity of 0 - Combinators like `+`
   and `~` also have no specificity
3. Inline styles have the highest specificity (other than !important)
   and count as the first number (1,0,0,0).
4. ID's (`#test`) count as the second number in the above set (0,1,0,0)
5. Classes, pseudo-classes and attribute selectors are the third number
   (0,0,1,0)
6. Type selectors and psuedo-elements (`p` & `::after`) take place of the
   fourth number, and are the least specific

Remember that if two rules have the same specificity and specify the same property the latter in the stylesheet will win.

So in your example `input[type="text"]` has *one* type selector and *one* attribute selector which means its equal to (0,0,1,1) versus the second selector which is only specifying *one* class (which is equal to an attribute selector in specificity terms), which is == to (0,0,1,0).

To override the previous selector, you can include a type selector, such as:

```
input.ui-state-error {
border: 1px solid #CD0A0A;
}
```

Despite the two selectors having the same specificity, the second will take precedence due to the nature of the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#cascading-order).

Comment: +1 for thorough answer :) Although, the specificity would be (0,0,2,0) if it is a descendant of `.ui-widget-header` or `.ui-widget-content`

Answer (score 3):

A type selector + an attribute selector is more [specific](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#specificity) than a class selector so it is applied later in the [cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can try input.ac_input ui-state-error { border: 1px solid #B5B8C8; }

Answer (score -2):

Try add style to

```
 #Applications.ui-state-error
```

Comment: This is just one example.  I have the same issue on other textboxes so i want a someone generic solution

Comment: You need to specify input[type="text"].ui-state-error to the group where you are changing the border colour